# What does the first part of this URL address 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion' do?

Tags: mongodb, url

I am watching a course about using MongoDB in NodeJS applications, this is one line of its codes:

```
const url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion';
```

Then it uses it like this:

```
MongoClient.connect(url).then((db) => {
...
}
```

I like to know what is the reason it uses the above address instead of the following?

```
const url = 'localhost:27017/conFusion';
```

Is there any difference? What is the reason for adding `mongodb://` in front of the URL address and what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mongodb://` is a required prefix to identify that this is a string in the standard connection format. It is as per the official documentation - [Standard Connection String](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#connections-standard-connection-string-format).

Standard connection schema is

```
mongodb://[username:password@]host1[:port1][,...hostN[:portN]][/[database][?options]]
```

Hence, you can't use `localhost:27017/conFusion` as mongodb connection string.

Answer (score 2):

"mongodb://localhost:27017/conFusion" points to your local MongoDB database created in MyMongoDB folder. The connect() method returns the database reference if the specified database is already exists, otherwise it creates a new database.